# Need an algorithm in c++ for xml document which is navigated through xpath

Tags: c++, xpath

In the following XML document...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<x:Response xmlns:xcr="http:sefgvsefraerdv">
<folder id='82273' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns'http://srdefaredr/folders.xsd'>
<folder id='104018' name='account'/>
<folder id='104019' name='aaaaa'/>
<folder id='82277' name='Desktop' system='desktop'/>
<folder id='82278' name='Trashcan' system='trashcan'/>
<folder id='82279' name='Documents'>
       <folder id='82280' name='Music'/>
       <folder id='82281' name='Pictures'>
            <folder id='82282' name='Nature Album'/>
       </folder>
</folder>
<folder id='82283' name='Public' system='public'/>
<folder id='82284' name='music1'/>
<folder id='82286' name='music'>
     <folder id='105744' name='abba'/>
</folder>
</folder>

</x:Response>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I need to get all the folder IDs and print them.

For example, I'm navigate like this:

```
  xpath.evaluate( /*/*/*/*/*[5])
```

I will get all the folders in Document. And from that I need to give `/*/*/*/*/*[5]/*`
To get Music and picture and `/*/*/*/*/*[5]/*/*` to get only Naturealbum.

and then go back all the way to `/*/*/*/*/*[6]`
and continue the same ..

Comment: Did you hand type that in? As it's got some syntax errors and also missing the namespace `x`

Comment: yes i did hand type.No big deal with syntax. only need the algorithm for navigation purpose :)

Comment: OK, just I copied it to test my answer and I had to fix it before it would work.

Answer (score 0):

To get all ids:

```
//folder/@id
```

If you have notepad++ there is a xpath plugin for it for testing out xpaths.

Comment: by giving //folder/@id i get only the folders aaa, documents, and so on.I could not get the folder id for Music, Pictures and Nature album and also abba

Comment: basically i have to give like this in case if i use name space             /*/*/*/*/*[local-name()='folder']/@id

Comment: Well I've tested it, all I can say is that your xml must be different to the one posted after I fixed it, or you are working with the broken xml. Post the actual valid xml.

Comment: its working fine if i give //@id thank since only folder id is there in the document.